# I don't know when I should use texture properties tab

Tags: texturing

[image]

All of a sudden, I wondered when I should use texture properties tab.

If I want wrap a object with a texture, I can achieve purpose in shade editor or material properties tab.

[image]

In other words, the texture properties tab is unnecessary when texturing  a object.

So I wondered why it is there.

I search in blender manual about 'texture properties' and found nothing.

I looked it up on YouTube, but the results were the same.

I just want to know the example it's actually used.

I need your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The textures tab is *almost* a holdover from before 2.8, when it was used for Blender Render textures.  In modern versions, it's still used for creating textures for use with some modifiers (like a displace) and for defining brushes for use with texture painting or sculpting.  It's not used for any materials.

Comment: thank you for good answer