# How to assign texture from the "texture properties" tab (Eevee)?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, properties

How can I assign a texture from the "Texture properties" tab to a material? This used to be simple in 2.79 but now all my textures are unlinked and I don't know how to assign them again. Thank you :)

Comment: hello, maybe this answer will help (basically you can't use these textures, you need to use the texture nodes that are available in the Shader Editor): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222519/i-dont-know-when-i-should-use-texture-properties-tab

Comment: So there is no longer a way to use a material colour and then modify it by using a texture?

Comment: you have texture nodes available in the Shader Editor: Shift A > Texture > Noise Texture for example, but they are not the same as the textures in the Texture tab (that are used for the Displace modifier for example)